# Javascript Tic Tac Toe horizontal check not working (Reduce)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe game, I got the following code:

```
let matrix = 3;
let moves = [[2,2,2],
             [1,0,2],
             [1,0,1]];

let checkWinner = () => {
    let winner;

    // Horizontal Check
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix; i++) {
        winner = moves[i].reduce((a, b) => (a === b) ? a : 0);
        if (winner)
            return winner;
    }

    // Vertical Check
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix; i++) {
        winner = moves.reduce((a, b) => {
            return a[i] === b[i] ? a[i] : 0;
        });
        if (winner)
            return winner;
    }
}

let winner = checkWinner();
if (winner) {
    console.log('player '+  winner + ' won the game');
}
```

The horizontal check here works, but the vertical check doesn't. Logically the code for vertical check does make sense to me and it should work. I think it has something to do with the reduce function.

Could someone tell me what is wrong the Vertical Check, and show me how I can get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you return from the function passed to `reduce` becomes its next first argument, so you need to return `a` instead of `a[i]` and check `if (winner[i])`.

```
const winner = moves.reduce((a, b) =>
    a[i] === b[i] ? a : [0, 0, 0]);

if (winner[i])
    return winner;
```

This is probably made nicer by converting a column into something that looks the same as a row and doing both checks with one function:

```
const lineWinner = line =>
    line.reduce((a, b) => a === b ? a : 0);

const checkWinner = () => {
    // Horizontal Check
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix; i++) {
        const line = moves[i];
        const winner = lineWinner(line);
        if (winner)
            return winner;
    }

    // Vertical Check
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix; i++) {
        const line = moves.map(row => row[i]);
        const winner = lineWinner(line);
        if (winner)
            return winner;
    }
};
```

Since it’s square, you can then do both at once if you want:

```
const lineWinner = line =>
    line.reduce((a, b) => a === b ? a : 0);

const column = i => moves.map(row => row[i]);

const checkWinner = () =>
    moves.reduce(
        (winner, row, i) =>
            winner ||
            lineWinner(row) ||
            lineWinner(column(i)),
        0);
```